# Azure Automation Runbook Import fails

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-automation

Importing a Runbook already available in Azure Automation requires the use of `-Force` in PowerShell. While this works for some, I get the following error for others:

> Import-AzureRmAutomationRunbook : BadRequest: Update runbook with
>   definition of different runbook kind is not allowed

Checked everything about the runbook type etc. and all seems OK. If I delete the runbook, then import and after that re-import (overwrite with -Force) then I no longer get above message.

But I need to be able to 'overwrite' the Runbooks to preserve the Webhooks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in ISE/Automation Add-on, which should be fixed soon. For the time being don't use ISE/Automation Add-on to upload runbooks. User portal or PowerShell `Import-AzureRmAutomationRunbook` form PowerShell (not from ISE).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. The problem was that the runbook which was supposed to be of type `PowerShellWorkflow` was earlier incorrectly imported as runbook of type `PowerShell`. After deleting and re-importing it worked fine for me.

**Also**, there was earlier a bug with the runbook cmdlets wherein the `Get-AzureRmAutomationRunbook` cmdlet returned the RunbookType value as `Script` instead of `PowerShellWorkflow` but as per the latest comment from the product team, it has been fixed.

Refer the [discussion on github here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/5679).